# Subtracting Dates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to take the difference(subtraction) between the last element of "donations" array with current Date.
I am trying following code but can't get this thing right, I have spent more like a day on this problem. Please do respond with solution.

```
db.users.aggregate( [ { $project: { dateDifference: { $subtract: [ new Date(), {"donations":{ $slice: -1 }} ] } } } ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$slice` returns portion of array. You need `$arrayElemAt` to return element from array at a given index.

Something like

```
db.users.aggregate( [ { $project: { dateDifference: { $subtract: [ new Date(), { $arrayElemAt:["$donations",-1] } ] } } } ]);
```